# Run a function on shutdown

Tags: c#

I am working on writing a program that will start automatically when the system boots.

and store that information in a DataBase when the computer is shutdown.

In other words, when the computer is shutdown, I show a *messagebox* for save information. if user click yes, save information in database.

```
 if (MessageBox.Show("Save changes?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        { 
        MyFunction();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this SystemEvents.SessionEnding event.

[MSDN Link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can get application shutting down from [FormClosing event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx).widows shutdown events can be get from [SystemEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx).